# How to add nested layouts in Ruby on Rails 4 with turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am trying to create a page with a nested layout as explained in the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts). Problem is that after creating the nested pages, the loading of the nested pages is slowed down a lot because it seems not to be compatible with turbolinks. **Has anyone got a solution for this?**

As an example I have a the basic `layouts/application` layout and in addition for admin pages I have a few more buttons added so this is added to a separate `layouts/admins` layout. Linking to the pages which use the admins layout takes a very long time because all the assets are being reloaded (it is not using turbo links).

Comment: Have you thought about using the same layout? but for the extra admin buttons doing something like => 

<input type="submit"> unless *admin*

Comment: the layouts are for pages that display admin tables, so the rows of the table are the view and the table itself would be in the layout, this solution would make the layout very heavy with ifs...

Comment: I'm having the same problem, was a solution ever found for this?

Comment: My solution would be to not use rails for templating and instead do templating client side with angular and something like ui router

Comment: @daslicious did you come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Nope. My previous comment is the best I got. Client side templating

Comment: i think i turned on caching for awhile `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true` in development.rb